# Pull request from Egit Eclipse plugin when using Bitbucket

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, bitbucket, egit, pull-request

Is it possible to make pull request from Egit Eclipse plugin. I use the Bitbucket repository and would like to merge branches
[image]

As you see, some branches have label **MERGED**. Can it be done from Eclipse without using Bitbucket interface?